# LinkedIn Not utilizing og:image

Tags: wordpress, image, properties, metadata

I've got a site that has multiple share buttons on entries in a WordPress site.

We designed this so there are no individual entries to view, they're Podcasts and videos. The listing page has a minimum of 10 entries, each with share buttons.

Currently the share links and titles are working correctly. But the page is not recognizing the og:image, and instead is picking up the default logo for the site itself.

I read another post on Stack Overflow that said it might be an issue for LinkedIn if the image is utilizing SSL for the link. But I just find that hard to believe.

The other issue I'm struggling with, the docs say once an image is scraped it stays cached for approximately 7 days.

I had an issue with FaceBook and there's a debugger that allows you to rescrape the page which let's me verify my changes worked.

My two questions are, is there something other than the og:image i should be specifying? since I can't specify it per post, it's in the head of the page itself, i would think it would pick that up. No?

Second, is there a way a developer can re-check after the meta info has been changed to see if the changes worked, without having to wait the TTL on the cache?

Comment: ugh, poorly worded. I have a single listing page that has a player for each entry, and each entry has share links

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
url/link?blah=1

url/link?blah=2

url/link?blah=3
```

to get around the cache.

This should trick it into thinking its a new page each time.

Can i get a link to test?

Comment: Can you help me a little what you mean by that? if I'm understanding your post, that's what we already do

I can get with you directly but can't post it publicly, it's a client site. How could I reach you? i looked on your profile but see no way to message someone.

Comment: Dangit, I didn't see this message from you until just now. Sorry for the delay. I emailed you. you're welcomed to delete your email in the comment now.

Answer (score 0):

**Anthony Walz** posted the correct answer. Through email he also helped another problem i had which corrected a new issue i didn't realize I had until i looked.

my LinkedIn shares were not picking up the show title, they were picking up the page description instead (i have several podcasts showing on one page, we don't use individual post pages, they all play from the listing.)

he pointed me to the [developer docs on formatting sharing links](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

Which gives a real world example - here:

```
    https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network
    &summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn
```

Thanks a ton for assist Anthony!